# How do I get the effect of GNU tar's --strip-components with git-archive?

Tags: linux, git, unix, gnu, tar

In broad terms, what I'd like is a direct tar-to-tar transformation where the result's root contains only a particular directory-subtree of the original.

To illustrate with an example, say I want only the [gitweb directory](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=tree;f=gitweb;h=1c6b6c70093af20513b074cd8d9802bc2584b674;hb=HEAD) from git's repository. Running

```
$ git archive --prefix=git-gitweb/ master gitweb | tar tf -
```

gives

```
git-gitweb/
git-gitweb/gitweb/
git-gitweb/gitweb/INSTALL
git-gitweb/gitweb/Makefile
git-gitweb/gitweb/README
git-gitweb/gitweb/gitweb.perl
git-gitweb/gitweb/static/
git-gitweb/gitweb/static/git-favicon.png
git-gitweb/gitweb/static/git-logo.png
git-gitweb/gitweb/static/gitweb.css
git-gitweb/gitweb/static/gitweb.js
```

but I want

```
git-gitweb/
git-gitweb/INSTALL
git-gitweb/Makefile
git-gitweb/...
```

The [manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) provides for extra backend-specific options, but attempting to pass `--strip-components` produces an error:

```
$ git archive --prefix=git-gitweb/ --strip-components=1 master gitweb | \
  tar tf -
error: unknown option `strip-components=1'
usage: git archive [options]  [...] ...
```

The tar backend isn't GNU tar anyway.

Someone in freenode's #gnu channel suggested [Tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/), but it doesn't understand the output of [git-archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html):

```
$ git archive master > old.tar
$ tardy old.tar new.tar
tardy: old.tar: file type ``g'' unknown
```

Yes, I could extract the output of git-archive with `--strip-components` and create a new archive of the result, but I'm trying to avoid using the filesystem as a temporary variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Archive that directory as the CWD and you won't have the extra path component:

```
(cd gitweb; git archive --prefix=git-gitweb/ master .) | tar tf -
```

Or use this syntax as suggested by the `git-archive` man page:

```
git archive --prefix=git-gitweb/ master:gitweb | tar tf -
```

Comment: Great, and it works with the `--remote` option to git-archive too!